# Finding volume of a cone with integration

Tags: calculus

I am very confused on where to start with the question, do I start by trying to create a triangle on the top somehow?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Let $ R $ be the ray of the base and $ Z $ be the height of the cone.

By Pythagoras, we have

$$(2R)^2=5^2+5^2\implies R=\sqrt{12.5}$$
and
$$\tan(45°)=\frac RZ=1$$
The volume of revolution  will be
$$V=\int_0^Zs(z)dz=$$
$$\int_0^Z(\pi r^2)dz$$

with

$$\frac rz=\frac RZ=1$$